# Why @Autowired not work out side a controller class spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception, autowired

I have a Spring MVC project. I have a class controller , service and dao layer.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonFacade personFacade;
   ....
}
```

I have my service class

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PersonFacadeImpl implements PersonFacade{

    @Autowired
    private PersonDAO personDAOdef;

    //code ....
}
```

And finally my DAO class

```
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
     //code
}
```

This works PERFECTLY, my problem its here:

I did a class listener and I would like use the PersonFacade with @Autowired

```
public class PersonListener extends AbstractRepositoryEventListener<Person> {

    @Autowired
    private PersonFacade personFacade;
    .... //code 
}
```

And I have this exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name      
'personListener': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is      
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:   
private com.gabrielglez.main.Facade.PersonFacade 
com.gabrielglez.main.evenlistener.PersonListener.personFacade; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of 
type [com.gabrielglez.main.Facade.PersonFacade] found for dependency: expected at least 1 
bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have this class in other package and I don't know why in this class Spring can't create the object and inside the controller works perfectly.

I don't know what is happening.

Here its my servlet-context : https://github.com/tsw1985/HelloHibernate/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml

In a few words, if I want to inject one dependency with @Autowired out side a controller class , I will have the same problem. Thanks to all.

Please if you help my you will save my life because I have one week with this problem.

Thanks to all !!

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: How about you create interface, implement your class to the made interface and then autowire the interface.

Answer (score 3):

@Autowired works only in objects which are managed by Spring. So annotate your class PersonListener for example with @Component and don't create instance as `new Object()`. Use for example @Autowired to get instance.

Comment: Himjames , Maybe I not explain fine my problem. The problem is : I want to Inject my PersonFacade class IN my LISTENER , because in the listener I want to do things with it. The problem is when I want inject that object in the CLASS Listener , I have a exception, but In the Controller I can use the PersonFacade with @Autowired always , but if I want to use that class in other class that is not a Controller , I have that problem. I need add something in the servelet-context.xml ??? Im frustrated with this.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I tried to explain you, that your Controller is managed by Spring because it is annotated @Controller. But your Listener is not annotated and it is not managed by Spring. So easy explain: You can inject objects only in injected object. And your Listener is not injected.

Comment: Himjames, finally I put a @Component in my listener class and I have the same problem. I dont know what is happening. Always I have the same exception. Do you know some example?

Comment: I don't know where and how you use PersonListener. How do you create instance of this class?

Comment: Im using it with lightadmin listener, you can see it in lightadming.org  in the section listeners. Im not do a instance of this class. There I have one method, onBeforeDelete() and this method its executed when I delete a row. But without listener, for example if I do a simple class that is not a controller  , and I want inject a class annotated by service, using autowired always I have that exception. Even I did @component and I have that exception, its impossible use a autowired outside a controller annotated class?? I would like see a example, can you download my project and try it?

Comment: OK if you are using lightadmin (I have never worked with it) and this class represents some component from this tool, there could be problem in some configuration or maybe springXjava version. Give full actual code on github, then I can try it.

Comment: Hiimjames you can download the project. https://github.com/tsw1985/LightAdminHibernate the problem is in : PersonListener.java, I have a comment. Update the Hibernate.cnf.xml to you configuration.Database name is 'prueba' . To access to lightadmin , write http://localhost:8080/main/admin in my case. I want only know the way how Can I inject a dependency OUT SIDE a controller class. Run the project and you will have the exception.

Answer (score 2):

You are using component scan on the package, but that component will not be automatically added as a managed bean because it does not have any of the annotations that the bean processor is looking for :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.gabrielglez.main" />
```

The [spring-context.xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd) documentation for `component-scan` says this (emphasis mine).

> Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be
>   auto-registered as Spring beans. **By default, the Spring-provided
>   @Component, @Repository, @Service, and @Controller stereotypes will be
>   detected.** Note: This tag implies the effects of the
>   'annotation-config' tag, activating @Required, @Autowired,
>   @PostConstruct, @PreDestroy, @Resource, @PersistenceContext and
>   @PersistenceUnit annotations in the component classes, which is
>   usually desired for autodetected components (without external
>   configuration). Turn off the 'annotation-config' attribute to
>   deactivate this default behavior, for example in order to use custom
>   BeanPostProcessor definitions for handling those annotations. Note:
>   You may use placeholders in package paths, but only resolved against
>   system properties (analogous to resource paths). A component scan
>   results in new bean definition being registered; Spring's
>   PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer will apply to those bean definitions
>   just like to regular bean definitions, but it won't apply to the
>   component scan settings themselves. See javadoc for
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan for information
>   on code-based alternatives to bootstrapping component-scanning

Comment: Ok, how can I fix the problem? Thanks. What is the anotation??

Comment: It is any of the annotations that I bolded. Look at your other class, it has the `@Service` annotation applied to it at the class level it is getting scanned. You need to add any of those annotations on your class and then your `component-scan` will pick it up, like the `@Component`.